# entropy estimation using histogram of normal data vs direct formula (matlab)

Tags: matlab, distribution, histogram, entropy

Let's assume we have drawn `n=10000` samples of the standard normal distribution.

Now I want to calculate its entropy using histograms to calculate the probabilities.

1) calculate probabilities (for example using matlab)

```
[p,x] = hist(samples,binnumbers);
area = (x(2)-x(1))*sum(p);
p = p/area;
```

(binnumbers is determined due to some rule)

2) estimate entropy

```
H = -sum(p.*log2(p))
```

which gives 58.6488

Now when i use the direct formula to calculate the entropy of normal data

```
H = 0.5*log2(2*pi*exp(1)) = 2.0471
```

What do i do wrong when using the histograms + entropy formula?
Thank you very much for any help!!

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code for the code? Are you using some central limit result?

Comment: NB `hist()` is depreciated, use `histogram()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `dp` term in the sum

```
dp = (x(2)-x(1));
area = sum(p)*dp;
H = -sum( (p*dp) * log2(p) );
```

This should bring you close enough...

PS,
be careful when you take `log2(p)` for sometimes you might have empty bins.  You might find [`nansum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nansum.html) useful.

Comment: Can you give me a short explanation why i need to add the width?

Comment: @user1569756 think of it as the `dt` term in the integration. The entropy is the inegral `t` in [-\infty \infty] of `p(t)log2(p(t)) dt`. You used this finite width to compute the area, you need to use it for the integration as well... Think of sampling as an approximation to the integral...

Comment: Correct, but as additional information @user1569756: That integral defines the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of a continuous random variable, which is distinct from the information entropy in the strict sense, which is only defined for discrete distributions.

Comment: @Masi it is very difficult to read code and error messages in comments. please consider posting as a new question

Comment: @Shai Should you have `H = -sum( (p*dp) * log2(p) ) / area`; in the last line instead. My entropy is otherwise very big, and you do not use `area` anywhere. With the division, my computed data is at about `-7.2`. What do you think?

Comment: @Shai Can you replace reliably centers (`x` and `p`) here by edges? Also what do you think about the division by `area` in `H`?

Comment: @Masi, using `hist` is an approximation for the integral. if you recall your calculus, when the bins are small enough the approximation using bins' centers is quite similar to using bins' edges.