# Matlab 'entropy()' on Normal RVs

Tags: matlab, entropy

If I estimate the entropy of a vector of standard normal random variables using the Matlab `entropy()` function, I get an answer somewhere in the region of 4, whereas the [actual entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) should be `0.5 * log(2*pi*e*sigma^2)` which is approximately equal to 1.4.

Does anyone know where the discrepancy is coming from?

Note: To save time here is the Matlab code

```
for i = 1:1000
  X(i) = randn();
end

'The entropy of X is'

entropy(X)
```

Comment: You can do `X = randn(1000,1);` But: "entropy uses 2 bins in IMHIST for logical arrays and 256 bins for
    uint8, double or uint16 arrays."

Comment: @Masi The 256 part is unrelated to the random number generation.  See the second paragraph of horchler's answer.

Comment: @chappjc I did and experimenting the linked answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16529739/54964

Answer (score 3):

Please read the help (`help entropy`) or [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) for `entropy`. You'll see that it's designed for images and uses a histogram technique rather than calculating the it analytically. You'll need to create your own function if you want the formula from Wikipedia, but as the formula is so simple, that should be no problem.

I believe that the reason that you're getting such divergent answers is that `entropy` scales the bins of the histogram by the number of elements. If you want to uses such an estimation technique you'll want to use [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) and scale the bins by area. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527672/entropy-estimation-using-histogram-of-normal-data-vs-direct-formula-matlab).

Comment: @Masi: I'm not clear the exact nature of your question. It's hard to help without code to reproduce the issue – maybe ask a new question? In any case, [`hist `](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) is now deprecated and The MathWorks strongly recommends using [`histogram`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html) instead. So if you're using a newer version of Matlab you should probably rewrite your code to use `histogram`.

Comment: Can you use `edges` to count the entropy similarly as `centers`? I think it should be possible but keep getting 0.06% difference.